# Remove advanced tab from Insert/Edit Media Dialog in TinyMCE 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to remove advanced tab from media popup. How can I remove this advanced tab? Can anyone suggest me?
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMnxT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration to do this in TinyMCE.  You can certainly modify the Media plugin's JavaScript file to remove this from the dialog.

If you look in the `../plugins/media` folder within TinyMCE you will find the JavaScript for the plugin.  If you look at plugin.js file you will find a section that defines the window/dialog:

```
win = editor.windowManager.open({
    ...
    body: [
      ... 
      {
        title: 'Advanced',
        type: "form",
        items: advancedFormItems
      }
    ]
```

The `body` array contains the tabs for the dialog.  If you remove the object that defines the Advanced tab it will no longer appear.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code to your editor configuration under init.

```
media_poster: false,
media_alt_source: false
```

Follow https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/media/#media_poster